# Create java.awt.Font from google/noto font

Tags: java, fonts, awt, chinese-locale

I have noto fonts installed (https://www.google.com/get/noto/) on my system but when I try to use some of the fonts (Chinese traditional, Chinese simplified) I receive just an empty space:

```
Font notoCJKtcfont= new Font("Noto Sans CJK TC Black", Font.PLAIN, 14);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test font");
JLabel chineseLable = new JLabel("大家好。 你好嗎＆23latinsymbolsδ");
chineseLable.setFont(notoCJKtcfont);
frame.add(chineseLable);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

Does it have something to do with OTF format and non-Latin symbols? Is there any way to use those fonts - so they will display correctly?

Comment: 1) `"Noto Sans CJK TC Black"` I see a `"Noto Sans CJK TC"` on the linked page, but not one that ends with `Black`. 2) Was the font registered with the toolkit? 3) Does that font support those characters? 4) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) Noto Sans CJK TC Black is font face of Noto Sans CJK TC font 2) I have installed font on system (Windows 10) 3) yes it should - according to documentation

Comment: 1) OK. 2) Got it, it should be OK. 3) I usually go down to asking the `Font` itself if it supports particular strings, but documentation is also good. 4) Where is the MCVE / SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched that "Java seems not to render many CJK OpenType fonts correctly".So, this can be related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7140863

https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

I installed the fonts like this

```
    private void render(Graphics g)
    {
        try
        {
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf"));
            font = font.deriveFont(24F);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(count), 50, 50);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(TestFont.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(TestFont.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```